# jQuery each function for all images under certain ul & li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get rid of lazyload load feature for certain images under a certain `ul`, so I wrote this following jquery

```
$("ul.wpmenucart").each(function() {
    $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').attr("src", $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').attr('data-src'));
    $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').removeAttr('data-src');
    $( "img.attachment-shop_thumbnail" ).removeAttr('data-lazy-type');
    $( "img.attachment-shop_thumbnail" ).removeClass('lazy-hidden');
});
```

But it's not working as I expected. What it's doing is - lets say I have 3 images under that ul & li tag and its just replacing the `img src` tqag with `data-src` tag value for the 1st image.

E.g. Lets say the 1st image url before running the jquery under ul tag was like this

```
<ul class="wpmenucart">
<li><img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="something" data-src="http://example.com/1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="something" data-src="http://example.com/2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

After running the above jquery it becomes

```
<ul class="wpmenucart">
<li><img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://example.com/1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Now can anyone plz tell me what I did wrong with my jquery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output looks correct since you removed the attribute data-src , $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').removeAttr('data-src');

Comment: Yah, but I wanna do that for each image. I know my jquery is wrong. Can you tell me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It would iterate through the each `img` with class `attachment-shop_thumbnail` and set/remove the attributes.

```
$("ul.wpmenucart").each(function() {
    $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').each(function()
    {
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('data-src'));
      $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
      $(this).removeAttr('data-lazy-type');
      $(this).removeClass('lazy-hidden');
    });    
});
```

Better approach:

```
$("ul.wpmenucart img.attachment-shop_thumbnail").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr('data-src'));
          $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
          $(this).removeAttr('data-lazy-type');
          $(this).removeClass('lazy-hidden');
        });
```

Comment: Oh! Works like a charm. Used the better approach one. I learn so many things from you guys every day. Thanks a ton for the help. :)

Comment: Thanks again for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what's wrong is that you're running the function for each `ul`, and not for each specific `li` item, so you have no indication as to which `li` item to get the info out of.

What you need is, after you make the loop for each `ul`, make another loop for each of it's `li` items, something like:

```
$("ul.wpmenucart").each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        img.attr("src", $('img.attachment-shop_thumbnail').attr('data-src'));
        img.removeAttr('data-src');
        img.removeAttr('data-lazy-type');
        img.removeClass('lazy-hidden');
    });  
});
```

See if that helps. Good luck.

Comment: You might wanna add something in your cart to see it

Comment: li and img are tags, not variables, you need to put quotes around them.

Comment: also, rather than finding img in li , just do $("ul.wpmenucart li img")

Answer (score 1):

`$("ul.wpmenucart")` selects a single element, your `<ul>`, which is probably not what you want.  Then, inside your `each` function, you select all `img.attachment-shop_thumbnail` elements in your entire document which is also probably wrong.

You want something like this:

```
$("ul.wpmenucart > li img").each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.attr("src", $el.attr('data-src'));
  $el.removeAttr('data-src');
  $el.removeAttr('data-lazy-type');
  $el.removeClass('lazy-hidden');
});
```

note the new selector and the use of `this` inside the `each` function instead of creating a second selector.